# Web scraping facebook "online friends list"

Tags: facebook, web, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am new to web scraping, and all I've done so far is some basic python scraping. What I really want is to have all my online friends on facebook scraped just to see how to scrape something that is changing dynamically. So please tell me is it possible,where to begin etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea behind scraping dynamic content is that the page with the content will be making requests in the background to some resource. You need to find out what those requests are, and then duplicate them, and parse the response. Often, the parsing side will be easier than normal scraping, because the response will be in a much more structured format, like JSON rather than HTML. An easy way to find the resource that is being called is by using the developer tools in your browser. In Chrome, hit F12 and check the "XHR" tab while on Facebook. You should see periodic requests to https://www.facebook.com/ajax/chat/buddy_list.php. Look at the data that is being posted, and what the response is. You will have to mimic those requests (including sending a valid cookie showing that you have logged in), and then parse the response.